# Neo4j Cypher has ultra-restrictive pattern comprehension - or am I using it wrong?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher

I recently picked up Neo4j as it seemed the best type of database to store data I'm currently scraping off a number of online discussion forums. The primary structure of the graph is Community -> Forum -> Thread -> Post -> Author

I'm trying to write the Cypher queries to resolve GraphQL queries, and would like to paginate (for example) the Forum -> Thread connection. The relationship is CONTAINS which holds an `order` property i.e. `(f:Forum)-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Thread)`

From the neo4j-graphql-js library I picked up on their usage of pattern comprehension to run an "inner query" on the child nodes. For example:

```
MATCH (f:Forum { id: $id })
RETURN f { .id, .name, .url, threads: [(f)-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Thread) | t { .id, .title, .url }] }
```

I'd really like to use ORDER BY, LIMIT and SKIP on the inner pattern comprehension, but unfortunately this is not supported: https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/issues/202 - the neo4j-graphql-js library gets around this by using `apoc.coll.sortMulti` but I've noticed performance is not great & a lot slower than if I were to use the ORDER BY clause on a top-level pattern equivalent.

Since I'm new to graph DBMS, this has got me wondering if I may have misunderstood how a graph DB is supposed to be used. From a "frontender" perspective, the ability to implement paginating in the lowest-level query language seems like a critical piece, but again, maybe I've not understood things correctly. Square peg, round hole, and all that!

Is this a fair evaluation? Is there another option in Cypher that will solve this? Or, should I just go back to use an SQL database for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDITED]

If you moved the `order` property into the `Thread` nodes (which should be valid if each `Thread` node is connected to only a single `Forum`), then you can create an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance) (or [uniqueness constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/schema/#cypher-intro-schema-constraints)) on `:Thread(order)` to speed up your query.

For example, this query should leverage the index to paginate forward faster (assuming that the `f.id`, the `order` value to use for pagination purposes, and `limit` value are passed as the [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) `id`, `order`, and `limit`):

```
MATCH (f:Forum)-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Thread)
WHERE f.id = $id AND t.order > $order
WITH f, t
ORDER BY t.order
LIMIT $limit
RETURN f{.id, .name, .URL,
  firstOrder: MIN(t.order),
  lastOrder: MAX(t.order),
  threads: [x IN COLLECT(t) | x{.id, .title, .URL}]}
```

And here is a (slightly more complex, but also fast) query for backwards pagination:

```
MATCH (f:Forum)-[:CONTAINS]->(t:Thread)
WHERE f.id = $id AND t.order < $order
WITH f, t
ORDER BY t.order DESC
LIMIT $limit
WITH f, t
ORDER BY t.order
RETURN f{.id, .name, .URL,
  firstOrder: MIN(t.order),
  lastOrder: MAX(t.order),
  threads: [x IN COLLECT(t) | x{.id, .title, .URL}]}
```

If you analyze the [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) of the above queries with various `$limit` values, you should see that the db-hit complexity is `O(F*L)`, where `F` is the number of `Forum` nodes (which is probably relatively constant) and `L` is the `$limit` value. So, these queries should be significantly faster -- with the index -- as long as:

```
F*L << (average number of `Threads` per `Forum`).
```

Comment: Brilliant @cybersam - do you know which part of the Cypher spec ensures the inner `COLLECT` only collects the right threads per forum? I removed the WHERE clause and ran the query and to my surprise it didn't collect the same set of threads for each result, instead it partitioned them per forum. Not sure I'm doing a good job explaining, but in contrast if the collect() was outside the "f { ... }" expansion, it would collect all threads from anywhere right?

Comment: Also it's a shame you can't have indexes on relationship properties. I can't move the order property because there are other list views of threads from other nodes that also need an order property on the relationship. Do you know if there really is no way to improve sorting performance on a relationship property, or anything in the pipeline that'll address this?

Comment: Not clear on why `order` nodes are really needed on the relationship. Are you saying that a `Thread` node can have multiple `CONTAINS` relationships, or something like that? Anyway, wrt `COLLECT`, read up on [aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) and how they use "grouping keys" -- the result you saw is exactly what should happen given the adjusted query.

Comment: I just tweaked my answer to provide queries for both forward and backward pagination.

Comment: You can look at [full-text indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.1/administration/indexes-for-full-text-search/), which do support relationship indexing but they use _string_ properties and are also require more effort on your part.

Comment: Would it be valid to just copy the `order` value into the `Thread` node (assuming each one only has a single `CONTAINS` relationship)?

Comment: there are other "Views of Threads" in the graph, e.g. from Author -> Thread, where the order value is specific to the view, and not to the threads themselves. However I have resigned myself to creating a new node between the major nodes, which I'm calling "Link" or "Connection" nodes, and storing the order property on those. Thanks for your help, it's been very insightful! The only thing I'm worried about now is that I thought this should have been a more simple solution, and I'm not sure any longer if neo4j is the right tool for me.